# Marshall a List to XML works - but how to unmarshall?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I can marshall a ObservableList using a "Wrapper"-class like below. But I cannot unmarshall it back to the wrapperclass it was before.

The idea is:
I have an ObservableList of "Expenses". I put this List into a wrapper-class and save this class to XML. The result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<List>
    <root>
        <category>[none]</category>
        <period>Year</period>
        <title>asd</title>
        <value>354</value>
    </root>
</List>
```

I cannot bring it back to the wrapper-object.
I really appreciate any kind of help.

**Main-class JAXBContext (visible for all):**

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyWrapperForList.class, Expense.class);
```

**Main-class SAVEBUTTON:**

```
public class SaveButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

        File serializedFile = new File(PATH);

        try {
            if (serializedFile.exists() == false)
            serializedFile.createNewFile();

            PrintWriter xmlOut = new PrintWriter(serializedFile);

            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            List<Expense> saveList = new ArrayList<>();

            saveList.addAll(data);



            MyWrapperForList<Expense> wrapper = new MyWrapperForList<>(saveList);
                JAXBElement<MyWrapperForList> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<>(
new QName("List"), MyWrapperForList.class, wrapper);



        m.marshal(jaxbElement, xmlOut);

            xmlOut.flush();
            xmlOut.close();
```

**Main-class-LOADBUTTON:**

```
public class LoadButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {


        try {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();




StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(PATH);
                MyWrapperForList<Expense> unwrapper = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml,
 MyWrapperForList.class).getValue();

            List<Expense> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            tempList.addAll(unwrapper.getItems());


            System.out.println(tempList.get(0).getTitle());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Wrapper-class:**

public class MyWrapperForList {

```
private List<Expense> list;

public MyWrapperForList() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}

public MyWrapperForList(List<Expense> expenses) {
    this.list = expenses;
}

@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
public List<Expense> getItems() {
    return list;
}
```

}

**Expense-class:**

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Expense {

```
private String title;
private String category;
private String period;
private String value;

public Expense() {} //Default constructor is needed for XML-handling

public Expense(String title, String value, String period, String category) {
    this.title = title;
    this.value = value;
    this.period = period;
    this.category = category;
}

@XmlElement(name = "title")
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

@XmlElement(name = "category")
public String getCategory() {
    return this.category;
}

@XmlElement(name = "period")
public String getPeriod() {
    return this.period;
}

@XmlElement(name = "value")
public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
}
```

}

I used this tutorial from Blaise Doughan: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html

Comment: What happens when you try to unmarshal?  I tried your example and everything works.  What does `ObservableList` look like?  Trying your example I made my `ObservableList` an empty subclass of `ArrayList`?  Does you example work if you just use `ArrayList`?  Which implementation and version of JAXB are you using?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: I'm glad that you answer here Blaise. :) I'm using the JDK 7 so I think I have the JAXB version 2.2. I also use an ArrayList like <p>ObservableList<Expense> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();</p> The line where it crashes is in the **"Main-class" - Last line** where I try to unmarshall the XML and link it to a wrapper-reference.

Comment: I see now, that the fault is somewhere else. The unmarshalling works, but the "Expense-Objects", which are saved in the ObservableList are initialized with null. Did I forget a step? If I save a List wich contains 2 Expense-Objects, I can show them with **System.out.println(data.get(0).getTitle());** If I do **System.out.println(data.get(3).getTitle());** an IndexOutOfBoundException will be thrown, which means, the 2 saved objects can be loaded but are declared with null.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: Today I understand what you wanted to say! I tried it with ArrayList and IT WORKED!!!!!! YAYY! But the point is, that I need an ObservableList because I use the "TableView" from JavaFX2.2, which bases on this type. I think I won't find a way to cast them into each other, or do you maybe have an idea? And why doesn't this work for ObservableList's? Thanks for your help Blaise! :)

Comment: I'll help with `ObservableList` now that we know that seems to be where the problem is.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: I'm looking now since hours for a solution and tried nearly everything my knowledge told me. I edited my questions with the full code. I would be really glad, if you could look over it Blaise. Everything is now made with ArrayLists. But it just doesn't want work. I can see no difference in the "test-tool" I did, which worked, exept that I didn't everything in multiple sub-classes.

Comment: I have added an answer that will hopefully help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MyListWrapper

If you want `MyWrapperForList` to unmarshal holding an instance of `ObservableList` then you will need to setup your class in one of the following ways.

**Property of Type `ObservableList`**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javafx.collections.*;

public class MyWrapperForList<T> {

    private ObservableList<T> list;

    public MyWrapperForList() {
        list = FXCollections.<T>observableArrayList();
    }

    public MyWrapperForList(ObservableList<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public ObservableList<T> getItems() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

**`List` Property Initialized to Instance of `ObservableList`**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javafx.collections.*;

public class MyWrapperForList<T> {

    private List<T> list = FXCollections.<T>observableArrayList();

    public MyWrapperForList() {
        list = FXCollections.<T>observableArrayList();
    }

    public MyWrapperForList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public List<T> getItems() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Input (nub.xml)**

```
<List>
    <root>
        <category>[none]</category>
        <period>Year</period>
        <title>dfg</title>
        <value>4</value>
    </root>
    <root>
        <category>[none]</category>
        <period>Year</period>
        <title>ROBO</title>
        <value>1234</value>
    </root>
</List>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyWrapperForList.class, Expense.class);

        //UNMARSHALLING
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum18594548/nub.xml");
        MyWrapperForList<Expense> wrapper = (MyWrapperForList<Expense>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, MyWrapperForList.class).getValue();
        List<Expense> data = wrapper.getItems();

        System.out.println(data.getClass());
        for(Expense expense : data) {
            System.out.println(expense);
        }
   }

}
```

**Output**

```
class com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper
forum18594548.Expense@789df61d
forum18594548.Expense@4a8927c8
```

---

**UPDATE**

> First: Thanks for you work Blaise!! I'm really glad for what you do to
>   me! I tried what you wrote here (it was nearly the same as I had) and
>   I got a similar (same type of) output as you got. BUT the objects in
>   the lists are all referenced with null. If I write
>   System.out.println(data.get(0).getTitle()); it says null. There is the
>   exact amount of objects in the list, but all attributes are referenced
>   with null. :(

I think I got tunnel vision on the `ObservableList` aspect only to miss your real problem was with how you mapped the `Expense` class.  Since you only have `get` methods you should map to the fields using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` as follows.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Expense {

    private String title;
    private String category;
    private String period;
    private String value;

    public Expense() {
    }

    public Expense(String title, String value, String period, String category) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
        this.period = period;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return this.period;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Comment: First: Thanks for you work Blaise!! I'm really glad for what you do to me! I tried what you wrote here (it was nearly the same as I had) and I got a similar (same type of) output as you got. BUT the objects in the lists are all referenced with **null**. If I write **System.out.println(data.get(0).getTitle());** it says **null**. There is the exact amount of objects in the list, but all attributes are referenced with **null**. :(

Comment: @TrudleR - I have updated my answer with what I think is ultimately causing your problem.

Comment: Haha, it works!!!! :D
Thank you very very much Blaise!!! I'm so glad about this! It was the last big step in my program. I see I have to study these annotations a bit deeper. Big thanks! :)